# Custom Membership Provider with custom login and registration forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I successfully implemented a custom membership provider and I'm able to login and register users via the Login controls and the CreateUserWizard controls.

But what I'm trying to acomplish is to create a custom login form on an aspx page with the same functionality as the login control. I will also need to create a "user administration" page where users can edit their own information and change their password. This functionality is not possible with just the vanilla Login controls. Is it possible to implmenet my own forms that use the custom membership provider?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question... Yes, it certainly is possible :) You might try adding some specific issues you're having to make your question more constructive.